# How to create array of cumulative sum of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I create a sequence of increasing numbers based on x? I might have arrays for x of which have 100,000 values so I cannot assume what x is.

```
x = np.array([0,2,9,6,1,3,6,2,8,6,10])
```

Desired array:

```
print(y)
np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

Comment: Please define "a sequence of increasing numbers based on x". It isn't clear how your `x` and `y` are related since the `y` is manifestly not the array of cumulative sums of `x` (despite the title of your question).

Comment: If what you really want for `y` is `array([ 0,  2, 11, 17, 18, 21, 27, 29, 37, 43, 53])` then just `x.cumsum()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment with my rep but I think we need more info. Are you essentially looking for the range of numbers that corresponds to the length of `x` but starting at 1? If so you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,2,9,6,1,3,6,2,8,6,10])
y = np.array([i+1 for i in range(len(x))])
print(y)
```

Edit:

@obchardon brings up a great point in the comments. Here is how you would use `np.arange()`:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,2,9,6,1,3,6,2,8,6,10])
y = np.arange(1,len(x)+1)
print(y)
```

Comment: There is a specific numpy function for that: `np.arange()`. `np.r_[]` and `np.linspace()` could also be used.

Comment: Added an example of `np.arange()`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An actual (but silly) *"cumulative sum of numbers"* solution as requested by your title:

```
y = (x * 0 + 1).cumsum()
```

Or:

```
y = (x == x).cumsum()
```